# Select among Three Numbers with different probability

Tags: imacros

How do i set this code(that is for 2 numbers) to select among  three numbers "0.5" , "0.75" and "1" and assign them a chance to be selected for example 20% "0.5" , 50% "0.75" and 30% "1" ?

```
SET !VAR1 EVAL("Math.random() > 0.6 ? '1' : '0.75'")
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SELECT ATTR=ID:t_score CONTENT=%{{!VAR1}}
```

Comment: iMacros works with JS files as well. In that JavaScript file, use the iim api and almost any vanillaJS .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should work:

```
Math.random() < 0.2 ? '0.5' : (Math.random() < 0.5/(0.5 + 0.3) ? '0.75' : '1')
```

Alternatively you also could use the following logic (but I don't know how to put that into iMacros):

```
var rand = Math.random();
rand < 0.2 ? '0.5' : (rand < 0.2 + 0.5 ? '0.75' : '1')
```